# Will app store and play store allow code updates?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native mobile app for iOS and Android. The service will be free through the app for a month because of a business requirement, users do not want to enter credit card info, but once the trial period of a month is over we would like to force the users to enter the credit card info & with that we want to have one more setting for users to manage the payment methods, update credit card info etc.

I was planning to add logic to force users to go to a credit card info screen and adding 'manage payment methods' through app updates both on iOS and android.

My question is, is it ok to do that or is it possible to do it this way ?The reason why we are skipping the payment thing for now is because we do not have enough time in our hands.

I would appreciate suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question belongs here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: err...but it is not exactly user experience related question, it is more about update of code with installed apps, may be I should edit the title?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with an app update, but on iOS you must use in-app purchases through Apple if the service is delivered in the app

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, and what should I do with android? read somewhere that there is android pay as well,

Comment: Andoid has its own in-app purchase system,  but I don't know if it is mandatory to use it.

Comment: On Android you are free to use any in-app purchase system if your choice.

Comment: @Rolfツ by using Google play in app and Apple in-app purchasing, can I have the user NOT to enter credit card info again and again, such as subscriptions payable every month and more or less storing credit card info like Uber does. I could understand that it might be Google or Apple which stores it by the way as apps cant do it according to PCI compliance.

Comment: Apple's in-app purchase system supports subscriptions. Users won't need to enter their credit card data every month. Note however that Apple takes a 30% cut the first year and less thereafter. And you won't get any data about your users (name, address, credit card number) from Apple.